# Trying to find the value of $h$ such that the set of vectors spans $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the value of $h$ so that the vectors $$a_1= (-1,h,7)$$ $$a_2=(4,-2,5)$$ $$a_3=(1,-6,2)$$ span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So, my attempt involved setting $a_1,a_2,a_3$ to be the column vectors of a matrix and then reducing this matrix to echelon form. Then there was a theorem we learned in class that the vectors will span $\mathbb{R}^3$ exactly when every row of the echelon form has a pivot position. However, I got really confused reducing the matrix to echelon form with an $h$, I've always did it with actual numbers, and with this the algebra got really messy. Could somebody help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better question is, for what $h$ values does the set of vectors not span $\mathbb R^3$? And to find the answer to this question, note that the vectors don't span $\mathbb R^3$ iff they are linearly dependent.

If they are linearly dependent, there exists some $x,y$ such that $a_1=xa_2+ya_3$. Hence, we have the following relations: $$4x+y=-1,\;-2x-6y=h,\;5x+2y=7$$So, $x=-3$, $y=11$, and $h=-60$.

So, the set of vectors spans $\mathbb R^3$ iff $h\neq-60$.

Comment: Isn't your assumption that we can write $a_1$ as a linear combination of $a_2$ and $a_3$ incorrect? Linear dependence does indeed tell us that one of the vectors can be written as a linear combination of the others, but it doesn't guarantee us that they all can... I think?

Comment: If any of them can, they all can. Just rearrange the equation. (There's a tiny exception to this, which is the case that $a_2$ and $a_3$ are dependent, but inspection shows that that isn't the case here).